# How to insert a list of string into a table of SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a table of 3 columns along with a primary key:

```
create table tempTable
(
    id int primary key identity,
    name nvarchar(50),
    gender nvarchar(50),
    city nvarchar(50)
)
```

And there is a list of string like this:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>() { "name", "male", "city" };
```

I want this list into the `tempTable`. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is both unclear and shows no effort.  Is the temp table ***really*** a temp table?  Are you using raw ADO.Net?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: there are a lot of ways to do it, what have you tired?  here is a link that shows you 1 way to insert the data into a table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001040/inserting-new-row-in-sql-database-table with that and a for each loop on your list you can accomplish it.  There are enve more ways too.

Comment: the name of the table is tempTable
I am using raw ado.net
here is my code so far. But I know, it is not making any sense.
List<String> list = new List<String>() { "A", "B", "C" };
            string qry = "INSERT INTO tempTable VALUES(@Column)";
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                foreach (var value in list)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@Column"].Value = value;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

Comment: @SafayatZisan - instead of adding it as a comment edit your question and add it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
string query="INSERT INTO tempTable(name, gender, city) VALUES (@name, @gender, @city)";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandString = query;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", list[0]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", list[1]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", list[2]);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            // your code...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Wow! I never had issues with AddWithValue(). But I think that's very interesting link. Thank you :)