# system.argumentexception column does not belong to table

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, dataset

I have a Defined Dataset with table `Customer` in it. I'm trying to add a row to this Dataset but I'm getting an error below is my code

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet1();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Customer");

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
   while(reader.Peek() >= 0)
   {
      string row = reader.ReadLine();
      string[] content = row.Split('|');
      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
      dr["mother_name"] = content[0];  // I'm getting an error here.
      dr["beneficial_name"] = content[1];
      dr["industry_code"] = content[2];
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);
   }

}

filestream.Close();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds);
```

So I'm getting an exception error in line `dr["emp_lastname"] = content[0];` the key exist in the table in my dataset. So I assumed that when I do dt.NewRow() it will create an instance of my dataset table row. How do I solve this? I just want to populate a row in my DataSet Table. Below is the screenshot of my Dataset

[image]

Comment: This is not how adding data to a database works. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001040/inserting-new-row-in-sql-database-table

Comment: @VDWWD I never mentioned that I'm trying to add a record to the db. My only aim is to add it to a dataset without using a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Dataset instance in `ds` and a DataTable instance in `dt`. That DataTable instance is not linked to your Dataset in anyway. The Datatable has therefore no columns.

Do a `dt=ds.Tables["Customer"];` instead to get an instance of the Datatable that conforms to the schema in your typed dataset.